# Trying to find what numbers two list have common

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

In my code, the computer is generating a 4 digit random number and then the code asks the user to give a 4 digit number. The target is to find what numbers are common between random number and the user's number. Like if the random number is 1234 and the user give 5432, the code output should be common numbers, in this case, 234.

The code is working fine except when user is giving all four number are same and it is also common in random numbers. like if the random number is 4569 and user give 4444 (all 4s and 4 is common also in the random number), instead of the result of 4, the code returns 4444. Any explanation?

```
import random

#generate a random 4 digit secret number

list1 = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
number = random.sample(list1, 4)
print(number)

#ask user for a 4 digit number

your_number = input("What's your 4 digit number: ")

#make a list of two numbers for convenience

number = list(number)
your_number = list(your_number)
print(number)
print(your_number)

#find how many numbers overlap between these two numbers, not position specific
overlaps = []
for k in your_number:
    for l in number:
        if k == l:
            overlaps.append(k)
        else:
            pass
print(overlaps)
```

Comment: The code is working when the user gives 0000. What error/unexpected result are you getting?

Comment: Please: make a minimal example (remove code which is not needed to reproduce the error) and say exactly what the problem is - "code is not working" does not say much.

Comment: it's like - if the computer generates 5439 and user give 5555 (all same character which is common with one of the computer's number) it just returns 5555. if the computer generates 4039 and user give 0000, it will return 0000.

Comment: If `number` is `0011` and `my_number` is `1100` then what is the expected outcome? `[]` or `[1, 0]` or `[0, 1]` or something else?

Answer (score 1):

Try to be more specific what the expected output is and why the actual output is considered to be incorrect. My initial impression is that perhaps you don't want duplicates in the output, i.e. if you're comparing `'5013'` with `'0000'`, you don't want the overlap to be `['0', '0', '0', '0']`, but instead `['0']`. If that's the case, simply replace the `if` statement as follows:

```
for k in your_number:
    for l in number:
        # if k == l:
        if k == l and k not in overlaps:
            overlaps.append(k)
```

This prevents overlapping digits from being recorded more than once.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because the outer loop(k) is your number. For every element in k, it will execute the inner loop(l) The first time it checks for the first '0' in your number against '1023', it finds 0 at index 1. In the next iteration it checks for second '0' in your number against '1023' it again finds 0 at index 1 and appends it to the list.

I am sorry if it did not make a whole lot sense. Please refer to the second image to get a better understanding.

Cheers

[image]
[image]